# Custom Boot Animation/Video

Tags: boot, omxplayer, vlc

Is it possible to make a custom boot animation with VLC player like you used to be able to with omxplayer? I've tried omxplayer as I did years ago but it looks like it's now being phased out and isn't working on Bullseye?
Doesn't have to be VLC specifically but it looks like that's what they're pushing instead of omx